# Why does my Access file grow so much after the DoCmd.TransferDatabase command? How to move one table from one .MDB Access file to another?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm preparing a Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) script in a *.accdb* file. (I don't have any requirement to do so, I just opened what I have: the Microsoft Access 2016 application, and opened its Visual Basic editor and started coding.)

**Goal:** The script is meant to move a table from an *.MDB* file to another *.MDB* file.
I couldn't find a way to do it directly, so I did that in 2 steps.

What the script does:

- 1st step: Transfers, or copies, a given table (stored in variable named *srcTableName*)
  from a local .MDB file (whose path+name+extension is in variable
  *srcPath*) into my script's file (an *.accdb* file called *Script.accdb*
  and stored in the same folder as the source *.MDB* file)
- 2nd step:
  Transfers, or copies, the table newly copied (named
  *intermediaryTableName*) from the script's current file to some .MDB
  file which is in some Drive (path+name+extension in *destPath*)

I couldn't merge the 2 steps into one (that is: to copy the table directly from *srcTableName* to *destPath*)

So, this is it: 
table in *.MDB* file, in local **->** table in current file (local, contains script, extension .accdb) **->** table in *.MDB* file, in some other drive

It works.

My **problem** is: each time I run my script, the script's file (which I sometimes call also. the "current file", or the *.accdb* one) grows 30MB more. This is unnaceptable. (I don't even save the file. Why does the file need to enlarge like this?)

I detected the problem comes from the command: ***DoCmd.TransferDatabase***. This command seems to increase the file size a lot.

After running the script: the script's file (a 500 KB file) has become a 27 776 KB one.

Followings runs:

- 27 776KB -> 54 912 KB (difference before and after run: 27 136KB)
- 54 912 KB -> 82 048 KB (difference: 27 135KB)

I have no idea what this command writes. I couldn't find any information on this on the documentation or in pretty much any google result. 
When I delete the table copied in the current file (the script's file) the size of the file almost does not shrink. So *DoCmd.TransferDatabase* seems to write something else (some metadata I didn't find, maybe)

I wish I could do the 1st step in some other way. Looking for workarounds:

- I was not able to configure programatically an *ADODB.Connection* in
  order for it to import the table from the old *.MDB* file (the
  *srcPath* one)
- *DoCmd.CopyObject* is a function that seems to please me, since it
  seems to create no "rubbish"/enlarge the file mysteriously. The
  available MSDN microsof's documentation provides no further details about the effects of applying this function or the arguments' formats, but it seems to be
  prepared to manipulate only objects that belong to the current file,
  and not an external file. I want to try to set its argument
  *SourceObjectName* to an external (that is: in another drive), detailed path, but it seems to only
  accept the table's (short) name. I tried to look some long-path name for access objects like tables, but also: the fields of the structure
  that contains the table I want to import
  (srcDB.TableDefs(srcTableName).Connect) seem to be empty for this
  table, and the "name" attribute only displays the name of the table I
  already know ("sh5") and can see as a user of Access, which seems to be of no use to
  specify the path to it from an external file.
- I was able to copy tables, or to export+import tables, from a "normal" access file (*.accdb* extension) to another *.accdb* file. As
  such, I tried to convert a *.MDB* file to *.accdb*, but was not successful. I got a
  ""The project cannot be converted into this format. The project can
  only be converted to Access 2000 or newer format." error message while using a
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application.ConvertAccessProject
  function.

I also tried to "compact and repair" the current/the script's file, setting the "Auto compact" option of the Access Application to True, but it didn't make much difference:
Next run: file size before this block of code: 82 048 KB
file size after that block of code: 82 048 KB
file size after script: 109 056 KB (difference before and after run: 27 008KB)

After all this:

Does someone have an idea to prevent *DoCmd.TransferDatabase* from enlarging the file like this?
Or another workaround to copy the table from one file to another?

Here is my code, should it provide any more useful details:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

'Copies one given table from the <srcPath> to a file <destPath> (This file serves as an intermediary. it contains the script and copies the table into a format I can manipulate and send to the destiny file.)
Sub CopyTableFromOneFileToTheOther()
Dim srcFileTitle As String 'file name (with no extension nor path) from which we want to copy the table
Dim srcTableName As String 'name of the table we want to move
Dim srcPath As String 'includes srcTableName, plus: old .MDB extension and path
Dim srcDB As DAO.Database
Dim destFileTitle As String 'file name (with no extension nor path) into which we want to move the table
Dim destPath As String 'includes destFileTitle, plus: extension and path
Dim destDB As DAO.Database 'file (access database) to which we want to copy the table to
Dim destTableName As String
Dim currentFilePath 'detailed path (included path, title, extension)
Dim intermediaryTableName 'name of the table held temporarily in the current file (the script's file)
Dim accessApp As Access.Application
Dim testTableName As String

'Initializations
srcFileTitle = "Actifs" 'This file is expected to be on local (in the same folder you put this file with script).
srcTableName = "sh5" 'table we want to copy / move
destFileTitle = "Actifs_toUpdate" 'title of the file to which we want to move the table. This file is expected to be somewhere remote. please update destPath as well.
srcPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & srcFileTitle & ".MDB"
destTableName = srcTableName & "_copy"
destPath = "G:\Users\b\bernarcl\Documents" & "\" & destFileTitle & ".MDB"
currentFilePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name
intermediaryTableName = srcTableName


Debug.Print "srcPath = " & srcPath & " | srcTableName= " & srcTableName
DebugPrint "currentFilePath = " & currentFilePath & "|" & "intermediaryTableName = " & intermediaryTableName
Debug.Print "destPath = " & destPath & " | destTableName = " & destTableName & vbNewLine

'Compact and repair current file, to see if enabling this prevents the file to grow 30MB
 Set accessApp = New Access.Application
 With accessApp
    .OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name
    .SetOption "Auto compact", True
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
    .Quit
End With

'Delete table form current file, if it already exists. Otherwise the file will store more and more of these, becoming too heavy.
If TableExists(srcTableName, CurrentDb) Then
    Set srcDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(srcPath)
    'testTableName = srcDB.TableDefs(srcTableName).Connect
    'Debug.Print "testTableName= " & testTableName
    'Dim t As TableDefs
   ' Set t = srcDB.TableDefs
    Debug.Print "Table " & srcTableName & " exists in file " & CurrentDb.Name & ". Let's delete it, and import the most updated one afterwards."
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, srcTableName
End If 'table exists


'Importing table of old file, in order to have it in a macro-compatible format
'PROBLEM of memory spending here. The file grows 30MB each time it runs this instruction.
'I didn't find equivalent and successful ways to transfer database table from one file to another: tried DoCmd.CopyObject, configuring ADODB.Connection's parameters,
DoCmd.TransferDatabase TransferType:=acImport, DatabaseType:="Microsoft Access", _
                     DatabaseName:=srcPath, ObjectType:=acTable, _
                     Source:=srcTableName, Destination:=srcTableName, _
                     StoreLogin:=True

If (fileExists(destPath)) Then
    Debug.Print "File " & destFileTitle & " already exists."
    Set destDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(destPath)
    If TableExists(destTableName, destDB) Then
        Debug.Print "Table " & destTableName & " exists in file " & destFileTitle & ". Let's update it."
        'DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, destTableName
        DoCmd.CopyObject destPath, destTableName, acTable, srcTableName 'This also warns the user and substitues the previous/current table with the to-be-copied one
        Else
        Debug.Print "Table " & destTableName & " does NOT exist in file " & destFileTitle & ". Let's create it."
        DoCmd.CopyObject destPath, destTableName, acTable, srcTableName 'creates table in destPath for the first time
    End If 'table exists
Else
    'create new file, before copying
    Debug.Print "file named= " & destFileTitle & " does not exist, then let's create it."
    Set accessApp = New Access.Application
    Set destDB = accessApp.DBEngine.CreateDatabase(Name:=destPath, Locale:=DB_LANG_GENERAL)
End If 'fileExists(destPath)
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, srcTableName 'deletes from current file. We don't need it here, anymore.
destDB.Close
End Sub

'Auxiliary functions
Private Function fileExists(ByVal strFile As String, Optional bFindFolders As Boolean) As Boolean
Dim lngAttributes As Long

lngAttributes = (vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem) 'Include read-only files, hidden files, system files.

If bFindFolders Then
    lngAttributes = (lngAttributes Or vbDirectory) 'Include folders as well.
Else
    Do While Right$(strFile, 1) = "\"
        strFile = Left$(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
    Loop
End If

On Error Resume Next
fileExists = (Len(Dir(strFile, lngAttributes)) > 0) 'If Dir() returns something, the file exists.
End Function


Private Function TableExists(ByVal srcTableName As String, db As DAO.Database) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Dim tdef As TableDef
db.TableDefs.Refresh
For Each tdef In db.TableDefs
    If tdef.Name = srcTableName Then
        TableExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next tdef
End Function
```

Comment: The file bloat is normal, though undesired, behaviour. It is really a cosmetic issue only, and doesn't indicate a malfunction.

Comment: Note that you can't compact and repair a file while it is open. It only works when the last open session closes. The compact and repair code you're using is only valid when using it on a different database.

Comment: @Gustav, do you know why it is normal that DoCmd.TransferDatabase makes the file bloat like this? in my case it is not only a cosmetic issue, it really makes the file heavier, and I have a limit for the size the file can reach that is easily overcome by this unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You're right!, many thanks. Running it from a script from another file has shrinked the file from 82 048 KB to ~500 KB. The only thing is that I would have to have a second script, outisde the first script's file, just for making the (first) script's file compacted-and-repaired. (I will think and figure out how to do it with only one file and not two)

Comment: You could just use `Application.SetOption "Auto compact", True` and it will auto-compact as soon as you close the database, as long as you're not worried about the size of the database while it's open.

Comment: The bloat is probably caused by a lot of temporary data being built for internal use only (as a later compact will shrink the file). You see the same bloat if you just relink a collection of already attached tables via ODBC. I know of no way to work around the issue.

Comment: Thank you, @Gustav

Comment: Thank you, @ErikvonAsmuth , you're right! After closing it, my 30MB file has just shrunk to 420 KB :)
This worked, as I don't have a problem with the size of the file while it is open.
Would you like to write this as an answer for the question, or should you just leave it in comments?

Comment: Leaving it in the comments is fine I guess, since it doesn't really answer the question posted in the title (as opposed to my actual answer, which is an alternative way to move tables between Access databases). Helpful flags on the comments (also those by @Gustav) don't hurt if you find them helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SQL query to move a table from one database to another.
Execute this on the source DB:

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable IN 'C:\MyOtherDb.MDB'
FROM MyTable;
```

I have used this a lot, and have never had these size problems.

You can also use SQL to pull in tables to the current Db.

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM [C:\MySourceDb.mdb].MyTable;
```

Obviously, you can use VBA to execute this query.

Note that some meta-information (indexes other than the primary one, lookup fields) might be lost.